# Strange Oracle error: Identifier too long ORA-00972

Tags: sql, oracle, erlang, odbc

I have faced this problem when working with ORACLE 10g. I read the answers given to this question here (**[[ora-00972 identifier is too long oracle 10g](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2788031/431620)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2788031/431620)**) on stack overflow but they have not worked for me. Perhaps my situation is different.

Now i had these table names:`WIMAX_TRAFFIC_STATS`  and `WIMAX_RADIO_STATS`. When i tried inserting data into them through an ODBC Connection with **[`Erlang/OTP`](http://erlang.org)**, i got the error:

```
{error,"[DataDirect][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-00972: 
identifier is toolong SQLSTATE IS: HY000"}
```

So, i searched google and found answers saying that maybe my table names are too long. So i did this below and tried again:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE WIMAX_RADIO_STATS RENAME TO WR;
Table altered.
SQL> ALTER TABLE WIMAX_TRAFFIC_STATS RENAME TO WT;
Table altered.
```

I am still getting the same error. Other sources sya that it could be the data i am writing in some of my columns. My table definitions are here below:

```
SQL> DESCRIBE WT;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -----------------
 SDATE                                              DATE
 ELEMENT_TYPE                                       VARCHAR2(50)
 MANAGED_ELEMENT                                    VARCHAR2(50)
 USER_LABEL                                         VARCHAR2(200)
 JOB_ID                                             VARCHAR2(50)
 MEAS_TYPE                                          VARCHAR2(50)
 MEAS_VALUE                                         VARCHAR2(50)
```

None of the data values i write there is longer than the column length definition. I really wonder. Am attempting to write strings that are less than 10 characters long in the table but yet still getting this error. **Some body help, please !**

**EDIT**
SAMPLE query request is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO WT(element_type,managed_element,user_label,job_id,meas_type,
meas_value) VALUES("BreezeMAX MBS",
"SubNetwork=ASN,MeContext=,ManagedElement=MBS.172.17.9.9",
"BMAX-Shoal2[MTN-Egate]",
"99297","rbMngmntPortPacketsDiscardedOnRx","0");
```

The SDATE field has a default set as `sysdate`

Comment: Please provide the erroneous query and data.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're using the wrong quotes.

```
VALUES('BreezeMAX MBS',
       ^             ^
```

Demo:

```
SQL> create table t (a varchar(100));
Table created.

SQL> insert into t(a) values ("qasdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdlmqmsldqsmldqsmldq");
insert into t(a) values ("qasdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdlmqmsldqsmldqsmldq")
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00972: identifier is too long

SQL> insert into t(a) values ('qasdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdqsdlmqmsldqsmldqsmldq');
1 row created.
```